# nightwatch.js browser.url is undefined (or client.url is undefined) with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to get nightwatch to call the `browser.url('http://www.google.com')` function call but it comes up as undefined (the following code was taken from the official docs at http://nightwatchjs.org/guide)

```
module.exports = {
    'Demo test Google' : function (browser) {
        browser
          .url('http://www.google.com')
          .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
          .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
          .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
          .click('button[name=btnG]')
          .pause(1000)
          .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
          .end();
     }
};
```

I have a project set up with something more simple, but my issue is any of the `browser` arguments that are referenced in nightwatch.js's docs come up as undefined

If I do

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(browser))
```

I get:

```
{"capabilities":{},"globals":{},"sessionId":null,"options":{"screenshots":false,"skip_testcases_on_fail":false,"log_screenshot_data":true,"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"internet explorer","javascriptEnabled":true,"acceptSslCerts":true,"platform":"ANY","marionette":true,"name":"MARSBPCHART"}},"launchUrl":"http://localhost","launch_url":"http://localhost","Keys":{"NULL":"","CANCEL":"","HELP":"","BACK_SPACE":"","TAB":"","CLEAR":"","RETURN":"","ENTER":"","SHIFT":"","CONTROL":"","ALT":"","PAUSE":"","ESCAPE":"","SPACE":"","PAGEUP":"","PAGEDOWN":"","END":"","HOME":"","LEFT_ARROW":"","UP_ARROW":"","RIGHT_ARROW":"","DOWN_ARROW":"","ARROW_LEFT":"","ARROW_UP":"","ARROW_RIGHT":"","ARROW_DOWN":"","INSERT":"","DELETE":"","SEMICOLON":"","EQUALS":"","NUMPAD0":"","NUMPAD1":"","NUMPAD2":"","NUMPAD3":"","NUMPAD4":"","NUMPAD5":"","NUMPAD6":"","NUMPAD7":"","NUMPAD8":"","NUMPAD9":"","MULTIPLY":"","ADD":"","SEPARATOR":"","SUBTRACT":"","DECIMAL":"","DIVIDE":"","F1":"","F2":"","F3":"","F4":"","F5":"","F6":"","F7":"","F8":"","F9":"","F10":"","F11":"","F12":"","COMMAND":"","META":""},"assert":{},"currentTest":{"name":"Demo test Google","module":"MARSBPCHART","results":{"steps":[],"passed":0,"failed":0,"errors":0,"skipped":0,"tests":0,"testcases":{},"timestamp":"Mon, 12 Mar 2018 18:00:40 GMT","time":0},"group":""}}
```

I was trying to get pageObjects set up working by making a `pages/` folder in my root directory and inside there I was trying to defined the `url` method/function but Im not quite sure if Im the one who should be creating this method/function to call or if the nightwatch.js's underlying library creates this for me

`browser.navigate` is also undefined for me.

again, is this something I need to implement myself or is it already included with nightwatch?

below is my `nightwatch.json` file:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["./tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "./pages",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false,
    "start_session": false,
    "server_path" : "./bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.edge.driver" : "./bin/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "internet explorer",
        "marionette": true,
        "javascriptEnabled": true
      }
    },

    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome"
      }
    },

    "edge" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my tests/MARSBPCHART.js file:

```
var searchCommands = {
    submit: function () {
        this.waitForElementVisible('@submitButton', 3000)
            .click('@submitButton')
            .api.pause(1000);
        return this; // Return page object for chaining
    }
};

module.exports = {
    testMe: function()  {
        console.log('in testMe')
    },
    url: 'http://google.com',
    commands: [searchCommands],
    elements: {
        searchBar: { selector: 'input[name=q]' },
        submitButton: { selector: '[type=submit]' }
    },
    page: function() {
        console.log('in page of MARSBPCHARTPage');

    },
    MARSBPCHART: function() {

        console.log('in MARSBPCHARTPage.js\' this.MARSBPCHARTPage')
    }
};
```

here is the whole project:

https://github.com/cotyembry/UITests

**Edit 1:** I failed to mention that I was running `java -jar ./bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar` manually in another terminal window

Thanks for all of your time and help, I really appreciate it

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to run internet explorer on Linux?

Comment: Your desired capabilities are wrong too, marionette property is only applicable for gecko driver, not IE.

Comment: And a last one, if you start the standalone selenium server manually, you have to provide the path to the driver as a command line argument

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are not starting the selenium process and session. All I did was copy your code and config and switched the values for `start_process` and `start_session` to true and it started working. There are other problems with your test but I did get it to run. To get `browser.url()` or `.navigate()` to work you need to start the selenium process and session. You can do that manually or by setting these values in the config to `true`.

[image]

Comment: I failed to mention that I was running `java -jar ./bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar` manually, but I did try what you said and put the values to `true` in `nightwatch.json` and now Im getting: `Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?` Ill do more research for this

Comment: Ahh, well it is likely failing to retrieve a session because you already had one started manually. As far as I know you can't start 2 of them. I'm not sure how to get around that aside from just letting nightwatch start the selenium server for you instead of doing it manually.